# Unity2D Script error - Type or namespace "Player" could not be found C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My Friend needs help!

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Obstacle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int damage = 1;
    public float speed;
    private void Update() 
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player")) {
            other.GetComponent<Player>().health -= damage;
            Debug.Log(other.GetComponent<Player>().health);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

`Assets\Scripts\Obstacle.cs(18,42): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Player' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

The player is called "Player", so not sure why it can't recognize it.
The script is on the obstacle.

Comment: Is it common not to use a `namespace` in Unity?

Comment: Basically you need to include the correct `using .... ` statement

Comment: previous comment is correct and if you hover your mouse on top of the "Player", it will tell you to implement missing reference.

Answer (score 0):

The error your friend is getting is being triggered by these two lines:

```
other.GetComponent<Player>().health -= damage;
Debug.Log(other.GetComponent<Player>().health);
```

The `GetComponent` fetches the first `MonoBehaviour` attached to the game object it's called on, of the type provided between the `<>` symbols.

This means that in your friend's case, he is writing code attempting to retrieve the first `MonoBehaviour` of the type `Player` attached to the `other` GameObject.

C# is a strongly typed language, meaning that when you use a type, you must have a definition of what that type means, or the code won't compile.

Let's look at the error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Player' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The compiler is telling us it is unaware of a `Player` type in this part of the code, so it refuses to compile.

Either the component you are trying to access (the one where the `health` parameter is stored), isn't called `Player`, or `Player` isn't visible to the compiler for some reason.

If the component type really is called `Player`, it's possible it is inside of a [namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/), or there could be some shenanigans going on with [assembly definitions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html).

Best way to tell would be if you updated your post with the `Player` script, or the one containing the `health` field.